# Routing in ReactJs, remove/unMount the parent component after the link is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am very new to ReactJS. I am trying to add a new link to the page and when I click on it, it should take it to a separate page and the parent component should be unMounted. I am using React Hooks. So when I am using routing, it does route to the new component correctly but it does not unrender the previous component

Code for

```
const GetCustomers = (props) => {
useEffect(() =>{ do something...});

 return (
<>
<ErrorBoundary>
        <Router>
          <>
            <Link to="/EditCustomer">Edit Customer</Link>
            <Route component={EditCustomer} path="/EditCustomer" />
          </>
        </Router>
</ErrorBoundary>
<Customer> Do alot </Customer>
</>

)
};
export default GetCustomers;
```

Code for EditCustomers

```
const EditCustomers= (props) => {
useEffect(() =>{ do something...});

 return (
<>

<div> Hello </div>
</>

)
};
```

So I click on Edit Customer, It goes to edit customer and show me Hello but it keeps showing the data for Customers component as well. How can I just move it to the newer component render and unMount the GetCustomers html

Comment: Take a look at https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch. Switches are used for rendering routes exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED
this is happening because Customer component is not inside the  so it will be always mounted, you should use a route for customer component too, here is an example i just made it might help you https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-aryabhata-o1g2g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your Sandbox does not have any route component?

Comment: @LearnAspNet sorry didn't save, I updated it you can check it now